# Running Appium with quantum framework in local gives "Unable to create driver instance in 1st attempt"

Tags: selenium, qaf, perfecto

I am relatively new to quantum framework and I was trying to set up an appium test through Quantum framework.

I have given below configuration in application.properties but when I am running it I am getting "Unable to create driver instance in 1st attempt".

```
remote.server=127.0.0.1
remote.port=4723
driver.name=appiumDriver
appium.capabilities.class=io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
appium.capabilities.deviceName=Nexus 5X API 24
appium.capabilities.appPackage=com.android.calculator2
appium.capabilities.platformName=android
appium.capabilities.appActivity=Calculator
driver.init.retry.timeout=60
```

Want to know how to call appium driver from this application. properties file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you have given wrong capability name to set driver class. Capability name used by qaf to set driver class is `driverClass`. So instead of

```
appium.capabilities.class=io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
```

try

```
appium.capabilities.driverClass=io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
```

Refer [how to use driver](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/how_to_use_driver.html) and [setting driver capabilities](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/setting_driver_capabilities.html)